# Show div when link is clicked below

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I need a way to create a dropdown. That shows a table above when a link is clicked below.

My HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="supposeToBeHidden">
        some content
    </table>
    <a href="#" id="btnToClickToShowTable">Click me</a>
</div>
```

It would be cool if the solution was in pure css, but not a must.

Comment: Pure css I don't believe but with very few JavaScript lines it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using css `:target` pseudo-class

```
<div id="container">
     <table id="hide">
        <tr><td>some content</td></tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#hide" >Click me</a>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#hide { opacity: 0; }
#hide:target {opacity: 1;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tdnyd/

More about [:target pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget)

Comment: Would it be possible to hide the table again if clicked a second time?

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard no, that's not possible... This is essentially the same answer as my CSS solution, just hides the target a bit differently.

Answer (score 2):

Pure CSS, but it won't collapse back up:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="hidden">
        <tr><td>some content</td></tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#hidden" id="btnToClickToShowTable">Click me</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hidden {
    display: none;
}

#hidden:target {
    display: block;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qVUqm/)**

Toggleable example, using the sweet [classList api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList). (vanilla js)

```
var el = document.getElementById('btnToClickToShowTable');
var sh = document.getElementById('hidden');
el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    sh.classList.toggle('show');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qVUqm/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible AFAIK with just CSS, but with jQuery, you can do this quite easily:

```
<div id="container">
    <table id="supposeToBeHidden">
        <tr><td>some content</td></tr>
    </table>
    <a href="#" id="btnToClickToShowTable">Click me</a>
</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#supposeToBeHidden").hide();
    $("#btnToClickToShowTable").click(function(){
        $("#supposeToBeHidden").toggle();
    });
});
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/LEK6P/

Answer (score 1):

Since I didn't see jquery tag, I though I'd show you how to do it with vanilla js:

```
var bindEvents = (function () {
    var button = document.getElementById("btnToClickToShowTable");
    button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var table = document.getElementById("supposeToBeHidden");
        toggle(table);
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}());
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edfke/1/